# using Drupal as webview for mobile app. Is it possible to 'view page as a certain user' using url parameter?

Tags: php, drupal, webview, drupal-7

I'm using Drupal to develop webview for mobile app.

Is it possible to 'view page as a certain user' using url parameter ?

for e.g. `http://localhost/drupal-site/node/1?uid=1`

It should not only 'view as', but also 'act as' the indicated user. For example, the user can comment in the webview in app using its own user account.

I hope that this question is clear enough. Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score -1):

There is a great module for this: [Masquerade](https://www.drupal.org/project/masquerade). The Masquerade module allows site administrators (or anyone with enough permissions) to switch users and surf the site as that user (no password required). The administrator can quickly switch back to their own admin account at any time.

Comment: yea. I tried that but it does not solve my problem. thanks anyway